# Using std::bitset for double representation

Tags: c++, double, bitset

In my application i'm trying to display the bit representation of double variables.
It works for smaller double variables. Not working for 10^30 level.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <limits>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

void Display(double doubleValue)
{
    bitset<sizeof(double) * 8> b(doubleValue);
    cout << "Value  : " << doubleValue << endl;
    cout << "BitSet : " << b.to_string() << endl;
}

int main()
{
    Display(1000000000.0);
    Display(2000000000.0);
    Display(3000000000.0);

    Display(1000000000000000000000000000000.0);
    Display(2000000000000000000000000000000.0);
    Display(3000000000000000000000000000000.0);

    return 0;   
}
```

Output:

```
/home/sujith% ./a.out
Value  : 1e+09
BitSet : 0000000000000000000000000000000000111011100110101100101000000000
Value  : 2e+09
BitSet : 0000000000000000000000000000000001110111001101011001010000000000
Value  : 3e+09
BitSet : 0000000000000000000000000000000010110010110100000101111000000000
Value  : 1e+30
BitSet : 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Value  : 2e+30
BitSet : 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Value  : 3e+30
BitSet : 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

My worry is why bitset always gives 64, zero for later 3. Interestingly "cout" for the actual values works as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at [the `std::bitset` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/bitset) you will see that it either takes a string as argument, or an ***integer***.

That means your `double` value will be converted to an integer, and there is no standard integer type that can hold such large values, and that leads to *undefined behavior*.

If you want to get the actual bits of the `double` you need to do some casting tricks to make it work:

```
unsigned long long bits = *reinterpret_cast<unsigned long long*>(&doubleValue);
```

Note that [type-punning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning) like this is not defined in the C++ specification, but as long as `sizeof(double) == sizeof(unsigned long long)` it will work. If you want the behavior to be well-defined you have to go through arrays of `char` and `char*`.

Comment: An alternative to type-punning in this case could be good old `std::memcpy`.

Comment: You need to use C++14 to get an `unsigned long long` constructor for `std::bitset`.

Answer (score 2):

With C++14, `std::bitset` now takes an `unsigned long long` constructor, so this might work:

```
union udouble {
  double d;
  unsigned long long u;
};

void Display(double doubleValue)
{
    udouble ud;
    ud.d = doubleValue;
    bitset<sizeof(double) * 8> b(ud.u);
    cout << "Value  : " << doubleValue << endl;
    cout << "BitSet : " << b.to_string() << endl;
}
```

This should give you the internal representation of a double. See the working sample code on [IdeOne](https://ideone.com/JNqVOu).

Comment: Unfortunately type-punning using unions is undefined in C++. It should work though.