# NAN Differences - std::nan vs quiet_NaN() vs Macro NAN

Tags: c++, c++11, nan

I was wondering what the differences between the following types of `nan` were. Except for the visual difference of `NAN_macro` (which evaluates to `-nan(ind)` as opposed to just `nan`), they all seem to behave the same (as per the sample script below).

I had a look at some other answers, e.g. [What is difference between quiet NaN and signaling NaN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18118408/what-is-difference-between-quiet-nan-and-signaling-nan). But I still don't quite understand why `NAN` is `-nan(ind)` whereas `std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN()` is `nan`, or why we have `std::nan("")` and `std::nan("1")` if at the end of the day they both seem to be the same concept.

Any explanations or clarifying links would be great.

```cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    using num_lim = std::numeric_limits<double>;

    const double NAN_macro   = static_cast<double>(NAN);  // -nan(ind)
    const double NAN_quiet   = num_lim::quiet_NaN();      // nan
    const double NAN_sig     = num_lim::signaling_NaN();  // nan
    const double NAN_str     = std::nan("");              // nan
    const double NAN_str1    = std::nan("1");             // nan
    const double NAN_strLong = std::nan("some string");   // nan

    const bool isnan_macro   = std::isnan(NAN_macro);    // true
    const bool isnan_quiet   = std::isnan(NAN_quiet);    // true
    const bool isnan_sig     = std::isnan(NAN_sig);      // true
    const bool isnan_str     = std::isnan(NAN_str);      // true
    const bool isnan_str1    = std::isnan(NAN_str1);     // true
    const bool isnan_strLong = std::isnan(NAN_strLong);  // true

    const bool not_equal_macro   = (NAN_macro   != NAN_macro);   // true
    const bool not_equal_quiet   = (NAN_quiet   != NAN_quiet);   // true
    const bool not_equal_sig     = (NAN_sig     != NAN_sig);     // true
    const bool not_equal_str     = (NAN_str     != NAN_str);     // true
    const bool not_equal_str1    = (NAN_str1    != NAN_str1);    // true
    const bool not_equal_strLong = (NAN_strLong != NAN_strLong); // true

    const double sum_macro   = 123.456 + NAN_macro;    // -nan(ind)
    const double sum_quiet   = 123.456 + NAN_quiet;    // nan
    const double sum_sig     = 123.456 + NAN_sig;      // nan
    const double sum_str     = 123.456 + NAN_str;      // nan
    const double sum_str1    = 123.456 + NAN_str1;     // nan
    const double sum_strLong = 123.456 + NAN_strLong;  // nan
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IEEE Standard 754 represents a `NaN` by a bit pattern with an exponent of all 1s and a non-zero fraction (note that all floating point decimal values are represented by a "sign", an "exponent" and a"fraction"), then, there are a lot of different NaN you can represent, as "a non-zero fraction" may be lots of different values.

To highlight your `NaN` representations, extend your code with this:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <limits>
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>

union udouble {
  double d;
  unsigned long long u;
};

void Display(double doubleValue, char* what)
{
    udouble ud;
    ud.d = doubleValue;
    std::bitset<sizeof(double) * 8> b(ud.u);
    std::cout << "BitSet : " << b.to_string() << " for " << what << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    using num_lim = std::numeric_limits<double>;

    const double NAN_macro   = static_cast<double>(NAN);  // -nan(ind)
    const double NAN_quiet   = num_lim::quiet_NaN();      // nan
    const double NAN_sig     = num_lim::signaling_NaN();  // nan
    const double NAN_str     = std::nan("");              // nan
    const double NAN_str1    = std::nan("1");             // nan
    const double NAN_strLong = std::nan("some string");   // nan

    ...

    Display( NAN_macro, "NAN_macro" );
    Display( NAN_quiet, "NAN_quiet" );
    Display( NAN_sig, "NAN_sig" );
    Display( NAN_str, "NAN_str" );
    Display( NAN_str1, "NAN_str1" );
    Display( NAN_strLong, "NAN_strLong" );
}
```

Even if it has has some UB (that could be fixed, see Ruslan comment), it does work to illustrate what I'm explaining below), this program outputs:

```
BitSet : 0111111111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 for NAN_macro
BitSet : 0111111111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 for NAN_quiet
BitSet : 0111111111110100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 for NAN_sig
BitSet : 0111111111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 for NAN_str
BitSet : 0111111111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 for NAN_str1
BitSet : 0111111111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 for NAN_strLong
```

They all have:

- "0" as sign (you'll probably get "1" for NAN_macro, as you report it as -nan, I don't). I used g++, I bet `NAN` macro may be defined differently by some compilers, I doubt this is part of C++ standard anyway.
- "11111111111" as exponent
- then different values of "fraction"...any actually, but never only zeros, else it would not be a NaN anymore.

Actually, this "fraction" or "payload" (see Ruslan comment) value can be used to store any information you'll like to store (as "why was there a nan here"?), this is called, [NaN-boxing](https://sean.cm/a/nan-boxing).

That's mainly why you may have "different" NaN values at some point ([quiet_NaN](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/quiet_NaN), [signaling_NaN](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/signaling_NaN) or any `NaN` you create conform to IEEE Standard 754...even if having different memory representations, thay are all `NaN` values (`x!=x` and `std::isnan(x)==true`).

So, to answer your questions:

> why NAN is `-nan(ind)` whereas `std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN()` is nan

Likelly because your compiler defined NAN macro like that, it may be different using another compiler. By the way, it's like min/max macros, even if one had the bad idea to define them, don't use them, prefer `std` functions which are part of the standard so should work the same with any compiler you use.

> why we have `std::nan("")` and `std::nan("1")` if at the end of the day they both seem to be the same concept.

Maybe "to help you play with NaN-boxing" could be an answer, even if I doubt those functions were created for that specific purpose. The right answer may just be "to let you decide what "fraction" value you want to use for your `NaN` if you need something different than `std::quiet_NaN` and `std::signaling_NaN`"

Sources:
https://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html

Also used https://stackoverflow.com/a/40737266/3336423 to output `NaN` memory representation.

Comment: You can avoid the UB due to union-type-punning by employing `memcpy`, see [How to implement fast inverse sqrt without undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24405129/673852).

Comment: What you call NaN "fraction" is properly called _payload_, and its purpose is to enable tracking the origin of the NaN. See [Why does IEEE 754 reserve so many NaN values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19800415/673852).

Comment: FYI. My compiler is MSVC 2019, and `NAN_macro` is `1111111111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`, i.e. `1` in the first bit. I guess that's why it displays as `-nan(ind)`.

Comment: @Phil-ZXX: I'm also seeing this with MSVC2015. I recommend that you never use MSVC macros anyway. Thanks for the bounty!